# Use cookiecutter-django-mysql to initialize the project and execute python manage.py migrate to report an error

Tags: python, mysql, django, cookiecutter-django

everyone. This is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow, please take care~

First
I created the project through  cookiecutter https://github.com/mabdullahadeel/cookiecutter-django-mysq and chose mysql5.7 as the storage database

Second
I specified the environment variable

```
export DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:123123123@127.0.0.1:3306/polo_testing_platform
export CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://localhost:6379/0
export USE_DOCKER=No
```

and I made sure my local mysql version is 5.7
[mysql version is 5.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJyvI.png)

Then
I get an error when I execute python manage.py migrate

error messages：

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, django_celery_beat, sessions, sites, socialaccount, users
Running migrations:
  Applying sites.0003_set_site_domain_and_name...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from django_site_id_seq' at line 1")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/manage.py", line 31, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 244, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 190, in database_forwards
    self.code(from_state.apps, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/contrib/sites/migrations/0003_set_site_domain_and_name.py", line 40, in update_site_forward
    _update_or_create_site_with_sequence(
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/contrib/sites/migrations/0003_set_site_domain_and_name.py", line 28, in _update_or_create_site_with_sequence
    cursor.execute("SELECT last_value from django_site_id_seq")
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/Users/polo/all_project/python学习/polo_testing_platform/polo_testing_platform/lib/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 254, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from django_site_id_seq' at line 1")
```

It looks like there is a problem with the code in this file 0003_set_site_domain_and_name.py
[error file and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AsRy.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am the maintainer of https://github.com/mabdullahadeel/cookiecutter-django-mysql
and the bug you faced has been resolved. Now you can create a project with MySQL database options and everything should work smoothly.